# Including facebook sdk but struggling to make fb api call within a function

Tags: php, function, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to create a function that makes a facebook api call. But when running the below code, it says that the Class 'Facebook\FacebookSession' not found. I tried to include require_once and use statements inside the function but "use" is not found. I also tried to just include the require_once but still doesn't work. I am not sure if it is possible to create a function to make a fb api call. Does anyone know how to include the classes inside the function?

```
  <?php
  require_once( 'autoload.php' );

  use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
  use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
  use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;

  use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
  use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;

  use Facebook\FacebookSession;
  use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
  use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
  use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
  use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
  use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
  use Facebook\FacebookServerException;
  use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
  use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
  use Facebook\GraphObject;
  use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;


        [some code]

  function post_allfriends();

   {

       [make fb api call]

   }

 ?>
```

Comment: Can you post the line of code that's throwing the error?